# How to post Facebook Score using JS SDK, without hardcoding the app access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a score using the JS SDK. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
FB.api("/[USER_ID]/scores", 'post', {score:score, access_token:"APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"}, function(response){
           if (!response || response.error) {
              log(response);
           } else {
              log(response);
           }
    });
```

However, I need to do this without hardcoding the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN. Any idea on how to do it using the JS SDK?

Answer (score 0):

`/me/` refers to the current user - when using the app access token there is no 'current' user - you're acting as the app - make the request to `/[USER ID]/scores` using the app access token

Comment: That solved the problem of the "official" code not working Igy! Thanks!

However, I still have to put the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN in my JS code... Any idea how to grab it dynamically using JS?

Comment: _“Any idea how to grab it dynamically using JS?”_ – __Don’t!__ Whatever this “anything” might be – everyone who sees your JS code could do the same thing, or even stept through it in their browser’s JS debugger, and they would have your app access token. __N-E-V-E-R__ publish your app access token client-side or transfer it to the client, in whatever way. If you need to publish something with your app access token (scores, OG actions) – __then do it server-side!__

Answer (score 0):

You can grab access_token through JS by using `FB.getLoginStatus`. More can be found in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).

.

Comment: The token you're referring is not the app access token, which is what's needed for posting a score.

Comment: No, it's not Ratul. I need the app access token. That's the user access token.

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry. I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, that I know of.
And, nor should there be, when you consider that the App will only have one app access_token.

Think of it like your app secret, keep it safe!
Especially when you consider how you get the access_token to start with, just by making a formatted request to FB with your ID and App Secret.

If you put that client side, then ANYONE could grab it and do stuff on behalf of your app!!

I would suggest one of two things:

1. Try making a call to /me/scores, and use the normal access token.
   Even though the API docs don't suggest this being possible, you never know.

OR
2. Encapsulate it as an AJAX call to your server, and make the Graph call from there.

Sucks, but there seems to be a few things that aren't quite designed to work on the client side yet. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Owen.

1. It doesn't work.
2. I'll give it a try! ;)